# format() - Weeks starting on Monday?

Tags: r, format

When using `format(as.Date(c("2020-10-04", "2020-10-05")), "%U")` (the first date is sunday, the second date is monday) I get week 40 for both dates. What do I have to do in order to let the week start on Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"%V"` :

```
format(as.Date(c("2020-10-04", "2020-10-05")), "%V")
#[1] "40" "41"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
format(as.Date(c("2020-10-04", "2020-10-05")), "%W")
```

Check out `?strptime` for the full documentation on it